Hide Sheet event object capture by onChange() function in Google Sheets
onChange() trigger function in general captures any change that is made to the specified sheets. But I want it to only capture the event change when someone is trying to unhide a specifically mentioned sheet.
I want to password protect some google sheets. So, the plan is when someone is trying to unhide the mentioned sheet, it should ask for a password and if the correct password is given the sheet should be unhidden. But the problem with the onchange function is that even after giving the correct password, it is again asking for password whenever I do some edit to the sheet. I only want it to ask for password when trying to unhide the sheet.
